# setInterval memory leak

Tags: javascript, memory-leaks

When using setInterval (which in itself seems to continuously increase heap size) in combination with changing an HTML element's content, Chrome's profiler shows an increasing number of nodes which aren't garbage collected. I've tried with both vanilla Javascript and jQuery, it makes no difference.

Any ideas on how to get around this? I'm just trying to create a simple clock that doesn't hog resources.

Snippet: https://jsfiddle.net/236Lkvao/

```js
updateClock = function() {
  document.getElementById('myDateTime').textContent = new Date();
}

setInterval(updateClock, 1000);
```

```html
<div id="myDateTime"></div>
```

Comment: Are you sure it is your code? Did you run this with all plugins disabled?

Comment: If that code (alone) leaks, it must be a bug in the engine.

Comment: I don't think it is memory leak, it is more like waiting to be garbage-collected. You don't get to decide when browser does garbage-collection, I suggest you create an isolate test for this function alone and run profiling for a few minutes, you should see the heap size drops then.

Comment: Yes, I've run this with plugins disabled, both in Google Chrome and Canary. It does not garbage collect, I've run performance profiling over several minutes, multiple times. It increases both heap size and node count indefinitely.

Comment: It seems to be a Chromium bug, so I've created an issue for it at their boards.

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=781738